# SqlConnection throws an exception

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

Dear professionals please help me with the following problem.
In my .NET C# application a have this code:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection( SQLCONNECTION_STRING );
```

It works marvelous on my development machine but throws an exception on Windows 2003 server. The application runs through CGI and has “Full trust” level.
I've tried several connections strings and I think the string doesn't cause the issue because even this code gets an exception:

```
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();
```

Thanks.

---

I found two weird facts:

1. It works if I connect debugger to process and simple trace the code.
2. It works if I run the application from command line (not through CGI as required).

So I guess something wrong with CGI and SqlConnection interaction. Does someone know about that?

Thanks everybody for responses.

---

Edited to add:

Here is my connection string:
"Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Users;User Id=user;Password=password;"

I've also tried several possible variants as described there: http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server

Please find information regarding the exception below:

```
The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor()
   at Test.Database.UpdateSQLServerDatabase(IDictionary`2 fields, String regName, StringBuilder regCode)
   at Test.Program.Run()

Type: System.TypeInitializationException

InnerException: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory' threw an exception. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Configuration system failed to initialize ---> System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.HasIllegalCharacters(String[] str)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String path)
   at System.AppDomainSetup.VerifyDir(String dir, Boolean normalize)
   at System.AppDomainSetup.get_ConfigurationFile()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths..ctor(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigPaths.GetPaths(String exePath, Boolean includeUserConfig)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.get_ConfigPaths()
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationHost.GetStreamName(String configPath)
   at System.Configuration.ClientConfigurationSystem..ctor()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.EnsureConfigurationSystem()
   at System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Configuration.PrivilegedConfigurationManager.GetSection(String sectionName)
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.GetConfigSection()
   at System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticsConfiguration.Initialize()
   at System.Diagnostics.Switch.InitializeConfigSettings()
   at System.Diagnostics.Switch.InitializeWithStatus()
   at System.Diagnostics.Switch.get_SwitchSetting()
   at System.Diagnostics.TraceSwitch.get_Level()
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPoolCounters..ctor(String categoryName, String categoryHelp)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlPerformanceCounters..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..ctor()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory..cctor()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..cctor()
```

Even parameterless constructor gives an exception. So I don't think the problem is in the connection string. I can see stack trace tells something about "Illegal characters in path". So I will try to drill down and find out. But maybe someone already knows solution.

Comment: What kind of exception is thrown ? What does the exception say ?

Comment: abd what does your connection string look like??

Answer (score 9):

This problem is generally related to a problem in your configuration file. You might want to re-create that.

Thanks,
Jivtesh

Comment: This problem for me was definitely a config issue.  I had set impersonation to required for all function calls (via serviceAuthorization/impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true" and also the OperationBehavior on each method) and then was testing with a call that was not utilizing impersonation.  Simply using the WCF test client or an improperly configured system.serviceModel tag that didn't set windows/allowedImpersonationLevel="Impersonation" will cause this exact error when you try to open a sql connection.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem when my `app.config` included an empty connection string section, like so;

```
<configuration>
    <configSections>
    </configSections>
    <connectionStrings>
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

From the sound of it, you've got a version that runs as both a console app, and a web app. That means you'll have an `app.config` for the console app, and a `web.config` for the asp.net site.

Since you have a working console app, try to spot differences between the equivalent sections and update the `web.config` to match your `app.config`.

Also, you might consider the different permissions inherent in the system -- the web site might not have permission to connect to the database because it is running as `IUSR_<machinename>`, but the console app is running under your own user credentials, and you are probably a machine administrator.

Comment: i tried i have win form and crystal report it added app config automatically if i remove app config my report not work if i include my connection string shows the error i added empty string as shown but still an error

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
string str="Data Source=[YourServer];Initial Catalog=yourdb;User ID=sa;Password=sa;";
SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(str);
```

Answer (score 0):

For me it was web.config trace misconfiguration, I had a misspelled

> System.Diagnostincs.TextWriterTraceListener

instead of

> System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener

and also had two trace elements... fixing those two issues solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the service is accesss able from the Browser, check the client side endpoint behavior configuration as :

```
<endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="clientEndpoint">
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
          <clientCredentials>
            <windows allowedImpersonationLevel="Delegation"/>
          </clientCredentials>
        </behavior>
</endpointBehaviors>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error thrown at the `SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection();` is correct but it is due to the error in App.Config the error message misleads.

Answer (score 0):

Checking the Inner Exceptions will tell what is the exact problem with your config file, you might need to do some drill down deep.